# PHP Preg match - Aceitar Acentos

Tags: php

Ola,
Tenho este codigo que criei, mas ele não aceita acentos...

```
 !preg_match('#^[a-z0-9\-+, .\#*()\\/]+$#i', $ads_title)
```

Como faço para que aceite acentos de qualquer letra?

Comment: tente adicionar `à-ÿ` à regex